# how to exit a stored procedure if a condition passes

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to stop my stored procedure in the middle when a if condition satisfies.
 i used NOEXEC ON  it shows all the above results till NOEXEC ON STATEMENT.
But i need only the if statement result without the above results is it possible.

```
DECLARE @var1  VARCHAR(MAX),
 @var2  VARCHAR(MAX),
 @var3  VARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @var1 = 'ASH'
 SET @var3 = 'ASHff'
 print @var3

IF @var1 <> ''
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'Information available'
    SET NOEXEC ON
    END 

    SET @var2 = 'DFGF'

    SET NOEXEC OFF
```

when i run it i got this result:

```
ASHff
Information available
```

but expected output is :

```
Information available
```

is it possible?

Comment: You are setting `@var3` and printing it, then check if `@var1` ... what are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: As `Veljko89` said, your code sequence does not make sense considering what you're trying to accomplish. Secondly, If you fix the sequence of print and IF condition then I would suggest you to use `RETURN` to immediately exit the SP.

Comment: if the if statement satisfies all the above print statement should not display. only the print statement in if statement should execute.

Comment: and what will the return -1 do?

Comment: RETURN immediately stops the execution of the remaining part of the SP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comment, I believe this is the order of steps you would want in the SP. You can stop execution on SP anytime you want by using **RETURN**.
Also I would not use NOEXEC, as based on your requirement we don't need to.

```
DECLARE @var1  VARCHAR(MAX),
 @var2  VARCHAR(MAX),
 @var3  VARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @var1 = 'ASH'
 SET @var3 = 'ASHff'

IF @var1 <> ''
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'Information available'
    return;
    END 

 print @var3

    SET @var2 = 'DFGF'


----------
```

Comment: yep it works fine nithin, but will the sp stop it process when it reaches return or continues till end and then shows result?

Comment: It will stop running remaining part of the SP when it encounters a `RETURN`.

Comment: Just today I encountered situation that procedure stops after return if called from Management Studio. But on production system when called from Java, it does not stop but continues. Very strange. Anybody has seen this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Also, other way to come out of a SP when a certain condition is met is to use GOTO

```
DECLARE @var1  VARCHAR(MAX),
@var2  VARCHAR(MAX),
@var3  VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @var1 = 'ASH'
SET @var3 = 'ASHff'

IF @var1 <> ''
 BEGIN
 PRINT 'Information available'
 GOTO xxxx
 END 

print @var3

xxxx:

SET @var2 = 'DFGF'
print @var2
```

You can also place xxxx right before the final END